# Tomcat LoginModule - access to httprequest

Tags: java, security, tomcat, servlets

I am running Tomcat 7 -  NOT using Weblogic or JBoss.  How do I get the LoginModule to get access to the HttpServletRequest?

I understand that you can do it via PolicyContext if you are in jboss and a similar method in weblogic.  But I am running neither JBoss or Weblogic.  I am running all Tomcat.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

I have a Filter that is called for every request, and in the Filter, I set some info into HttpSession.  In my LoginModule, I need access to that info.

Again, I am NOT running Jboss or Weblogic - which is the only way I've seen so far that people have gotten access to the Request.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 7 does not give access natively to the httprequest from a LoginModule (unlike JBoss 7). You need to implement it by your own.
For that, you could use the same principle than JBoss does :

- create a valve which stores the current httprequest in a ThreadLocal (org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve in JBoss)
- retrieve the current httprequest in your LoginModule by simply reading the value stored in the ThreadLocal (JBoss uses the PolicyContext object and the handler org.jboss.as.web.security.HttpServletRequestPolicyContextHandler for that)